# Multiple SSL Certificates break Apache

Tags: apache, ssl, https, centos, vhosts

I have a website that uses HTTPS (already setup and working).
Now I am trying to add a second website with HTTPS, but when I restart apache, apache crashes (without an error).

In the error_log I find this:

```
    [Wed Mar 07 03:41:14 2018] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.6.33 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Mar 07 03:42:16 2018] [notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
[Wed Mar 07 03:42:16 2018] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Mar 07 03:42:16 2018] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Mar 07 03:42:32 2018] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Wed Mar 07 03:42:32 2018] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Mar 07 03:42:32 2018] [notice] Digest: done
```

My VHosts look like that:

**Working:**

```
    <VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/page/eng
    ServerName www.page.com
    ServerAlias page.com

    ErrorLog logs/page.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/page.com-access_log common

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/page_certificate.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/page_private_key.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/page_INTERMEDIATE.cer
</VirtualHost>
```

**Not Working:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/page/de
    ServerName www.page.de
    ServerAlias page.de

    ErrorLog logs/page.de-error_log
    CustomLog logs/page.de-access_log common

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/page.de_ssl_certificate.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/page.de_private_key.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/page.de_ssl_certificate_INTERMEDIATE.cer
</VirtualHost>
```

As long as "SSLEngine on" is not active on the second entry, everything works fine.

Any idea what the issue is / could be?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

One idea is that your Apache version Apache/2.2.15 needs one more directive to allow name Virtual Hosting (in 2.4 it's no more necessary). Use it in the server context, not in the virtual host itself of course.

[NameVirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost)